# How to get all simple product's quantity and SKU with SQL Query

Tags: magento-2.1, stock

I just don't know how to get all simple product's stock and SKU information with SQL Query. I just need to get something like this

```
SKU       Quantity   Stock Status
---       --------   ------------
454645       50           1
545878       15           1
```

Any help please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use following query :

> "SELECT cpe.`sku`, csi.`qty`
> FROM `catalog_product_entity` cpe
> RIGHT JOIN cataloginventory_stock_item csi ON cpe.entity_id = csi.item_id
> GROUP BY cpe.`sku`
> ORDER BY cpe.`sku` ASC";

You can check in stock or out of stock according to the returned quantity

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't know why two column I have which is product_id and item_id. Both are same.

Comment: glad i can help

Comment: product_id instead of item_id worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Here is my result. Maybe someone will need this. This is for v2.1.5. And to get only simple products.

```
select catalog_product_entity.sku, cataloginventory_stock_item.qty, cataloginventory_stock_status.stock_status from catalog_product_entity
    join cataloginventory_stock_item on catalog_product_entity.entity_id = cataloginventory_stock_item.product_id
    join cataloginventory_stock_status on catalog_product_entity.entity_id = cataloginventory_stock_status.product_id
    where type_id = "simple";
```